# Stop object finalize event when google cloud storage object is renamed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

```
hint: this doesn't need a code sample
```

I'am working with google cloud storage and cloud functions, the case demands triggering the function when an object is uploaded via [(`Object finalized`) event](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage), the chain goes as listening to the event from cloud functions, generate a random string, call some api that commits to a db, and rename the same object with the random string attached, when this happens -renaming the object via `bucket.rename_blob`- , google cloud storage triggers the finalize event again thus the same function is called again in a randomly-ended loop (noticed uploading an object generates about 23 names in the db), anyway to stop propagating the event when the object is renamed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we can read in the doc for [`bucket.rename_blob`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest/google.cloud.storage.bucket.Bucket#google_cloud_storage_bucket_Bucket_rename_blob), this method "copies blob to the same bucket with a new name, then deletes the blob". This is why your Cloud Function is triggered again and again, since each time you rename an Object a new Object is created, which triggers the `finalized` event.

The only way I can see is to store in a DB the new Object name and, in the Cloud Function, check if this name is present in the DB: If it is present you don't execute the Cloud Function business logic since this Object name is the one of a renamed object.

You can very well use Cloud Firestore as the DB to store those names, or any other DB of your choice

Comment: thank you @Renaud Tarnec, unfortunately i can't miss hitting the database, i've just narrated the question in a simplified way, but it's good to know from an expert as yourself that there isn't a way around it, i'm accepting the answer.